# Inequality with integrals

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am having a problem with the following exercise.

Let $f$, $g$ be continuous non-negative functions on $[a,b]$, and let $C$ a positive constant.

Suppose that: $f(x) \leq C+ \int_{a}^x f(t)g(t)dt$,

for all $x \in [a,b]. $ Show that:

$$f(x) \leq C\exp\left(\int_{a}^x g(t)dt\right).$$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(x):=\int_a^xf(t)g(t)dt$. Then $g(x)(C+h(x))\geq h'(x)$. So $h'(x)-g(x)h(x)\leq Cg(x)$. Now multiplying by $\exp\left(-\int_0^xg(t)dt\right)$, we get 
$$\frac d{dx}\left(h(x)\exp\left(-\int_0^xg(t)dt\right)\right)\leq Cg(x)\exp\left(-\int_0^xg(t)dt\right),$$
and integrating 
$$h(x)\exp\left(-\int_0^xg(t)dt\right)\leq C\int_0^xg(u)\exp\left(-\int_0^ug(t)dt\right)du.$$
The RHS is $C-C\exp\left(-\int_0^xg(t)dt\right)$, so 
$$h(x)\leq C\exp\left(\int_0^xg(t)dt\right)-C.$$
As $h(x)\geq f(x)-C$, we get the wanted result.

Comment: Can you detail a bit more. I do not see how to use this..

Comment: $h'(x)=f(x)g(x)$ and $f(x)\le C+h(x)$.

Comment: Why do I multiply by $\exp\left(-\int_0^xg(t)dt\right)$ ?

Comment: The LHS will be the derivative to a product.

Comment: what is does LHS stand for?

Comment: Left Hand Side.

Comment: If I understood correctly, we will obtain an inequality related to f'(x) and then I can conclude the inequality of f(x).
However, I don't find this expression. Please help with this last step

Comment: I've added details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6288/discussion-between-user43418-and-davide-giraudo)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the idea of wansik inequality in ODE

Comment: I can't use that

Comment: I can only use properties regarding differentiation and integrals

Comment: If you need to answer a question in a certain way, you should say so when you ask the question, by providing context and a description of what attempts you have made.  It is frustrating to answer a question only to have the goalposts move.

Comment: ok sorry about that. I am still new to the website

Comment: That being said, what is the "wansik inequality"?